# Distributing an enterprise (in-house) iOS app

Tags: ios, mobile

I am curious as to the process for distributing an iOS app for in-house use.  As far as I'm aware you must have an enterprise license.  Other questions indicate that Apple simply gives you a key to sign the apps and you can distribute the raw IPK files.  Does the company have to register the devices with Apple?  I'm sure Apple would not simply give people app signing ability as they can use this to circumvent the appstore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple to develop applications for in-house use.
If it's for a company (other than yours), they will have to buy an enterprise license and you will just have to compile your code/generate the application using this certificate. There is no need to register any device and the application does not need to pass through the Apple review process or through the Apple Store.

Recently Apple has released a new [certificate (namely B2B)](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) which offers you more possibilities to distribute with companies. May be this will help you.

Comment: This is for my company.  Are you sure there is no device registration?  What would stop a rogue developer from creating an app, signing it as an "enterprise app" and putting the ipk on their website?  Since it's signed it will run on all iphones.

Comment: We use the in-house certificate for internal applications into my company and we don't need to register the devices. There is no way to verify whether the devices belong to the company... It's just illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misreading the question earlier.

This manual is more related to what you would be doing: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en%5FUS/Enterprise%5FDeployment%5FGuide.pdf